# How to insert text at either end of the android textview?

Tags: android, textview

Is it possible to have a textview which contains some text at the leftmost side and some text at the rightmost side of the textview. 
For Example: I want to have a textview which should appear like this 
/////////////////
text         a 
////////////////

Comment: With the help of one textview it is not possible.If you take two text views then it is possible.

Comment: textView.setText("text" + stringVariable + "a"); Or am I missing the point?

Comment: You can use a jugad textView.setText("text" + "   SPACE   " + "a");   ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible using a single TextView.
Just put the text in HTML format like

```
  <string name="my_string">
<![CDATA[
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <body>

    <h1><span>Sunil bn</span><span style="float:right">Your Text</span></h1>
    </body>
    </html>
]]>
    </string>
```

in the strings file. Suppose the name of the string is "my_string". Then in your code set the text on the TextView using

```
myTextView.setText(Html.fromHtml(getResources()
                    .getString(R.string.my_string)));
```

Answer (score 1):

No its not possible with single TextView.

You can try `textview.setText("test _____   "+"a");` but it will not work perfectly.

But you can take **two** `TextView` then you can achieve this.

Comment: Ya I know it is possible if i use two textviews but i wanted to achieve this in a single text view. There is android:drawableEnd which can do this but i need to provide the image instead of text.

Answer (score 0):

```
textView.setText("text" + spaces(10) + "a");

String spaces(int numberOfSpaces){

    if (numberOfSpaces < 1){return "";}

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(" ");

    for (int i=1;i<numberOfSpaces;i++){
       sb.append(" ");
    }

    return sb.toString();

}
```