# How to make a textview which flows up

Tags: android, textview

```
___________    ___________    ___________      ___________    ___________    ___________
|         |    |text1    |    |text1    |      |         |    |         |    |         |  
|         |    |         |    |text2    |      |         |    |         |    |         |  
|         |    |         |    |         |      |         |    |         |    |         |  
|         |    |         |    |         |      |         |    |         |    |text1    |  
|         |    |         |    |         |      |         |    |text1    |    |text2    |  
|_________|    |_________|    |_________|      |_________|    |_________|    |_________|
```

first three shows what happens when I call myTextView.append("text1\n"); myTextView.append("text2\n"); in the order. but I want it to be like the second three. how can I achieve this, or does this already exist?
any guesses or offers are welcome, thanx in advance.

PS: there is no limit for lines, it should be scrollable also.

edit: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12671467/how-to-insert-text-at-either-end-of-the-android-textview?rq=1) it says aligning to right using html, so I am thinking of using html but not sure. link:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set `android:gravity="bottom"` on the `TextView` in your XML layout.  That will align it to the bottom of the view, and as you add to it the contents should push up.